# How to add HTTP Headers to the nutch index?

Tags: nutch, websolr

I'm attempting to use nutch with [Websolr](https://websolr.com). Their authentication method [requires adding headers](https://websolr.com/guides/websolr-advanced-auth) to HTTP updates.

To accomplish this I imagine I would have to write my own Nutch plugin and extend the [getCommonsHttpSolrServer](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/trunk/src/plugin/indexer-solr/src/java/org/apache/nutch/indexwriter/solr/SolrUtils.java?revision=1453776&view=markup) method. Is there a way to do this without writing my own plugin?